# React renders my Component before it actually has Data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-hooks, lifecycle

So I'm hard stuck on this Problem... normally I would just do a "ComponentDidMount" but since I'm trying to avoid using classes and only use react hooks I got stuck with the Problem.

My Component renders before it gets any Data from the API, so my .map function won't work as it has not recieve any data.

Shop.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { listShops } from "../../Redux/actions/shopActions";

const Shop = () => {
  const userShop = useSelector(state => state.shop);
  const auth = useSelector(state => state.auth);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(listShops(auth));
  }, []);

console.log("Look at my userShop",userShop.shop)
  return (
      <div>
       {userShop.map(shop=>(<div>{shop}</div>))}
              {console.log("How often do I Render?")}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Shop;
```

ShopAction.js

```
import {GET_SHOPS} from "./types";

export const listShops = userData => async dispatch =>{
    const userId = userData.user.id;
    await axios.get(`/api/shops/shops/user/${userId}`)
    .then(
        res => {
        const user = res.data;
        dispatch({
            type: GET_SHOPS,
            payload: user.shops
        })})
}
```

shopReducer.js

```
const initialState = {}

export default function(state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
      case GET_SHOPS:
        return {
            ...state,
            shop:action.payload
        }
      default:
        return state;
    }
  }
```

Comment: I just noticed that somehow i'm getting an Object with Array stored... Even so my Console Browser says:  [{...}[...}{...}]  .... looks for me like an Array but when i check with typeof it says it's an Object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(!userShop){
   return <h1>loading<h1>;
 }
 return (
     <div>
      {userShop.map(shop=>(<div>{shop}</div>))}
   </div>
 );
```

Comment: Oh yes it worked...I made a mistake and actually try to render the whole shop Object again after mapping, instead of the single elements. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

Return an empty array if `state.shop` is `undefined` using [short-circuit evaluation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Short-circuit_evaluation):

```
const userShop = useSelector(state => state.shop || []);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return (
     <div>
      {userShop && userShop.map(shop=>(<div>{shop}</div>))}
   </div>
 );
```